# What dns server can I extend using database queries?

Tags: c++, dns

Essentially I want to do the following:

```
string resolveDns(string host){
    string rootId = "SOME_ID";
    string id = rootId;
    string []zones = host.split('.');
    for (int i = zones.count() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        id = getZoneId(id, zones[i]);
    }
    string []ips = getZoneIps(id);
    if (ips.count() == 1){
        return ips[0];
    } else {
        return getLeastLoadedIp(ips);
    }
}

string getZoneId(string rootId, string zoneName){
    return Sql.prepare("SELECT id FROM zones WHERE parent_id=%s AND name=%s", rootId, zoneName);
}

string getZoneIps(string id){
    return Sql.prepare("SELECT ip FROM zones WHERE parent_id=%s", id);
}

string getLeastLoadedIp(string []ips){
    if (inMem){
        int min = INT_MAX;
        string ip = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ips->count(); i++){
            int count = HashTable.get(queue_length, ips[i]);
            if (count < min){
                ip = ips[i];
                min = count;
            }
        }
        return ip;
    } else {
        return Sql.prepare("SELECT ip FROM zones WHERE ip IN (%a) ORDER BY queue_length ASC LIMIT 1", ips);
    }
}
```

What DNS server would allow me to do this? (C or C++ is fine)

Comment: @BoPersson what do you mean? this code would run on the dns server. the more important feature that i need is the retrieval of the ips from the database.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Thought this was somehow supposed to run on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (not sure) PowerDNS supports custom back-ends. Another approach (just dreaming) could be using normal database back-end, and use some SQL stored procedure that would alwas return least loaded IP. Also, many DNS servers are open source, thus you can modify the code to your needs. Also, BIND10 is going to be something modular and is going to support extensions (don't remember how exactly the call them), mabe this functionality could be added as such "extension". But I think this BIND10 feature is not ready yet.

Don't forget about TTL. Probably your approach makes sense with low TTLs only.

I think some commercial solutions have this feature, probabl F5 does, but I guess that's not what you are up to.